# how to make a tool or userControl then add it in any project later c#

Tags: c#, user-controls

Im looking to make a tool .. which is a file browser using listview C#
im sure there's a way to save this tool so i can add it in any project i would make later with out righting the code again .. how can i do that ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Make the UserControl in a library (dll) project. Then you can reference the library in other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your `UserControl` to a Class library. Then you can add the `Usercontrol` from the library (`dll`) to your `Toolbox` in Visual Studio.

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Creating a Windows Form User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)